# I have both a German student visa and a French Schengen visa (for travel), now the student visa is expired but the French Schengen visa is still valid

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am a non-EU student who has both a German student visa and a French Schengen visa (for travel), now the student visa is expired but the French Schengen visa is still valid.
I entered the Schengen area (arrived in Paris) on 02/Oct/2019 (and got a stamp on the French visa page), and my German student visa is valid from 01/Oct/2019 to 31/March/2020. My French visa is valid until 24/June/2020. I've applied for the German student visa extension but I haven't received it yet
For further information, I got my French C-type visa (issued on 25/June/2019, valid till 24/June/2020) before I received my German D-type visa (issued on 01/Oct/2019, valid till 31/March/2020). I entered the Schengen area on 02/Oct/2019 (at this time I have both visas already, and both of them are un-used before this date)
In this case, can I still travel inside the Schengen countries (and leave before 24/June/2020?